# How to underline the whole cell in html

Tags: html

when I use the `<td><u>test</u></td>`. I just underline the test but not the whole cell. The underline do not extend to the whole cell. Could I ask how could I underline the whole cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the cell a border at the bottom.

```css
td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4trev/).

Comment: Bottom border and underline are two different things. So while this might do what was actually wanted, it does not answer the question that was actually asked.

Comment: @Jukka I was trying to achieve what the OP wanted, just as you said, since you don't "underline" a cell, but its text. Rather you use border for a cell and that's an appropriate and simple way to achieve the desired result. I don't see the point of complicating things here, but it is good that you point out the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Make u to be block element to fill whole cell and then you can apply css style to it:

```
u { display:block; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
```

Comment: This implies adding `u` markup and creates both an underline for text inside the markup (only) and a bottom border for the block that is as wide as the cell. So it does not extend the underline, and it adds a border that was not requested for.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot underline “the whole cell”, because underlining in CSS relates to text only. So you can underline the entire textual content of a cell, but not the cell as such.

To make the underline stretch from the left edge of the cell to the right edge, you would need to set the horizontal padding of the cell to zero (the typical default for them is 2px) *and* to make the cell width equal to the width of the text. The latter can normally be achieved by *not* setting the width of the cell and by not having any cell in the same column that needs a larger width than the cell under consideration.

It is difficult to see *why* you would want to do so, and it is quite possible that you do not actually want an underline but a border.